# Equilibrium proof question in research paper.

Tags: proof-verification, research

I am an engineering student who has just started researching.
Because of lack of mathematical knowledge, some evidence is difficult to understand. If you can handle this, give me some hints.

First, the formulas used in the proof process.

$v_k(\theta)$ = 
\begin{cases}
\lambda p - c , & \mbox{if }\theta \mbox{ $\geqq h_k$} \\
0, & \mbox{if } \theta \mbox{ $< h_k$}
\end{cases}

$p_k(\theta' \mid \theta)$ = 
\begin{cases}
1 - \alpha , & \theta \geqq h_k \text{ and } \theta' = \min\{K_k, \theta + 1\} \\
\alpha , & \theta \geqq h_k \text{ and } \theta' = \theta - 1 \\
\alpha, & \theta = h_k \text{ and } \theta' = 0 \\
1,  & \theta < h_k \text{ and } \theta' = \theta + 1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}

$r(\theta, a)$ = 
\begin{cases}
\min\{K_k, \theta +1\} , & \mbox{if  } a = H \text{ and } \theta \geqq h_k \\
\theta - 1, & \mbox{if  } a = L \text{ and } \theta \geqq h_k + 1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}

$v^{\infty}_k(\theta^{(t_0)}) = \mathbb{E}( \sum_{t=1}^\infty \delta^t v_k(\theta^{(t)})) = v_k(\theta^{(t)}) + \delta \sum_\theta' p_k(\theta' | \theta^{(t_0)})v^{\infty}_k(\theta') $

Based on the above formulas, the contents of the proof are made, but this part is not understood.

At,  $\theta \geqq h_k +1 $ and $a = H $ 
so consumes a cost c. 
So, Workers r increase $min\{K_k, \theta +1\}$ with the probability $ 1 - \alpha $ and decreases to $\theta - 1$ the probability $\alpha$. 
Hence workers function $V_\theta (H) = \lambda p - c + \delta[(1-\alpha)v^{\infty}_k(\min\{K, \theta_+1\}) + \alpha v^{\infty}_k(\theta-1)]$

I understand above function. But, I can't understand this part.
$ a = L $ , worker saves cost c. 
And, workers r increase and decrease becom $\alpha \ and \ 1 - \alpha $.

$V_\theta (L) = \lambda p + \delta[(1-\alpha)v^{\infty}_k(\theta-1) + \alpha v^{\infty}_k(\min\{K, \theta_+1\})]$

I think 
$V_\theta (L) = \lambda p + \delta[(\alpha)v^{\infty}_k(\theta-1) + (1 - \alpha) v^{\infty}_k(min\{K, \theta_+1\})]$
is right function.

plz give me any advice for me.

Comment: It looks like random formulas have been strung together, with no explanation or context.

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you show us what the equilibrium proof is via a link or formatting, etc, in order for us to help you. Also, you have the function $v_k(\theta^{(t)}))$ which has an odd number of parantheses, so please fix that.

Comment: @user477343 This is the link of research paper. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6195597/   Thanks.

Comment: No problem and thank you. I also proposed an edit where I use **\text{...}** which is essentially the same as **\mbox{...}**, namely what you have used. I also used **\min** for the $\min$ function, and you can use that for better formatting in your last formula you wrote :)